# the concept of NAN and is_nan() function in php

Tags: php, nan

What is the concept of NaN in PHP? When and where is it used, and why this is useful?

What is this below function used for? And please, I need an explanation of the code below.

```
<?php echo is_nan(200) . "<br>"; echo is_nan(acos(1.01)); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

NaN means "Not a Number". We basically call imaginary numbers (eg: Complex Numbers) as **NaN**, for eg: square root of -1 (*i*), `acos(1.01)`. These numbers cannot be computed / calculated.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php#62504):

> nan/"not a number" is not meant to see if the data type is
>   numeric/textual/etc..
>
> NaN is actually a set of values which can be stored in floating-point
>   variables, but dont actually evaluate to a proper floating point
>   number.
>
> The floating point system has three sections: 1 bit for the sign
>   (+/-), an 8 bit exponent, and a 23 bit fractional part. There are
>   rules governing which combinations of values can be placed into each
>   section, and some values are reserved for numbers such as infinity.
>   This leads to certain combinations being invalid, or in other words,
>   not a number.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php) of `is_nan()` function:

```
bool is_nan ( float $val )
```

> **Details:** Checks whether val is 'not a number', like the result of acos(1.01).
>
> **Returns** TRUE if val is 'not a number', else FALSE.

**So, basically this function is used for checking the validity of return values of mathematical functions and operations, and expects a float as a parameter.**

Now, **200** is a valid number. So, `is_nan(200)` will return `False`.

While, `acos(1.01)` is trying to find arc cosine of **1.01**. From Mathematics, we very well know that cosine function returns value in the range of **-1** to **+1**. So value of 1.01 (more than 1) cannot exist. Hence, `acos(1.01)` cannot be determined. Thus it is not a valid number. Hence, `is_nan(acos(1.01))` will return `True`.